# Admin rights on a secure Access Database

Tags: ms-access, password-recovery

I am again in a bit of a situation and am hoping someone might help me with this. I am truly stuck and would appreciate any input.

I have been tasked with retrieving a password from an Access database. It is a .mdb file . I also have the corresponding .mdw file

The .mdb file and .mdw file are both configured to only have a specific member of the Admin group, "adminDBA", who can change any permissions or anything of the sort for the file. The log-in information I have for the Access database is NOT an admin user, it is a normal user. However, the files themselves are NOT locked so password-cracking software doesn't work.

Can anyone possibly provide me with any instructions on how I might elevate myself to the admin group if it is locked (w/o using an admin account to do so), or retrieve the passwords? (I do have the .mdw file, but can't edit that). I will answer any questions I can. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Any of these suitable?: [access user level password recovery](https://www.google.com/search?q=access+user+level+password+recovery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sergei Gavrilov's tool works like a charm to crack relatively short passwords. mine was 8 characters with capitals/lowercases/numbers and it cracked.

http://ntaccess.tripod.com/infosite.htm